# Problemas com POM

Tags: xml, spring, pom

Estou fazendo um curso de spring mas estou tendo um problema com o arquivo pom.xml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

essa é a descrição do problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Este é o código fonte**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Ola @Matheus, Bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. Algumas dicas para sua pergunta, tente colocar o codigo e o erro escrito ao inves de imagem, isso vai ajudar a comunidade a entender melhor seu problema. =D -- [ask]

Comment: Poste o código fonte do pom.xml que fica mais fácil de verificar

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta usar acima do  as informações de parent:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```